# How do I wipe the data from a hard bricked phone

Tags: unbricking

I think I've hard bricked my Android, and the phone had sensitive private data on it while it was still functional. I plan to try and get it repaired, but is it possible to wipe this data first?

Comment: If it's hardware brick than phone is literarlly brick there is no repair.

Comment: If by *hard bricked* you mean you can't even access recovery, then as @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје says, no chance.

Comment: Repairing a phone like that is often more expensive than buying a new one.  And the good news is that if you have synchronized with Google then a new phone will have the option of restoring your apps and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very definition of bricked is that the phone is totally inoperable.  But on the off chance that it is just a screen problem there are a couple of possibilities.

Try the HDMI output.  See if there is any sign of life.  If so, then either using the screen digitizer or an external USB mouse, do the normal Settings, Backup/Restore/Set to Factory thing.

Another idea is to try booting up a PC with a Linux LiveCD of your choice and see if you can access the phone at all.  If so, then go about deleting what you can.

If it is truly bricked, then perhaps it is time to go shopping.  Walmart Online has some good deals.

Answer (score 0):

DO THIS ONLY TO WIPE IT THERE WILL BE NO RECOVERY!!!
Try the Google Lost My Phone Method to wipe the phone clean:

1.go to https://www.google.com

2.Simply type "Lost My Phone" or "Find My Phone"

3.Click On Recover (You may or may not need to log in, MAKE SURE TO LOG INTO THE SAME GOOGLE THAT IS ON THE PHONE)

4.A page should appear, all the way at the bottom there will be "Consider Erasing your phone"

5.Click on that and follow further instuctions
Good Lucks.